# How do I delete an element from the list and from the UI in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, user-interface

[Image of the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AZQh.png) I want to delete an item of type  `BasketItem` from `BasketItemList` and also remove it from the UI. I made two external class. Here is the code:

`BasketItem` class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:pharmacist_app/Models/basket_item_model.dart';
import 'package:pharmacist_app/controller/basketController.dart';
import 'package:pharmacist_app/widgets/basket_item_lists.dart';


class BasketItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const BasketItem({super.key, required this.item, required this.index});
  final BasketItemModel item;
  final int index;
  @override
  State<BasketItem> createState() => _BasketItemState();
}

//int counter = 0;
bool isThereAnItem = true;
BasketItemsList objList = BasketItemsList();

class _BasketItemState extends State<BasketItem> {
  void removeItem() {
    setState(() {
      objList.items.removeAt(widget.index);
    });
  }
  //call this function in ontap of that delete button

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 120,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              //color: const Color(0xffffffff),
              //  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0))),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  //image
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 13.0),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        widget.item.image,
                        width: 100,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // const SizedBox(
                  //   width: 20,
                  // ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              //NAME
                              widget.item.name,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
                                color: Color(0xff003A71),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            //price
                            Text(
                              '${widget.item.price} SR',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
                                  color: Color(0xff003A71),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                  ),
                  //button
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 10,
                        height: 40,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xff88BFDD),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(30),
                          ),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              offset: Offset(1, 2),
                              blurRadius: 3,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: GetBuilder(
                            init: BasketController(),
                            builder: (controller) {
                              return Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      //controller.increment(widget.item.counter);

                                      setState(() {
                                        controller.counter++;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    icon: const Icon(
                                      size: 18,
                                      Icons.add,
                                      color: Color(0xff003A71),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  //Text('${controller.counter}'),
                                  Text('${controller.counter}'),
                                  controller.counter > 1
                                      ? IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            // controller.decrement(
                                            //   widget.item.counter);
                                            setState(() {
                                              controller.counter--;
                                            });
                                          },
                                          icon: const Icon(
                                            size: 18,
                                            Icons.remove,
                                            color: Color(0xff003A71),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      : IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              isThereAnItem = false;
                                              removeItem();
                                            });
                                          },
                                          icon: const Icon(
                                            size: 18,
                                            Icons.delete,
                                            color: Color(0xff003A71),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                ],
                              );
                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Divider(
          thickness: 1,
          color: const Color(0xff013a71).withOpacity(.2),
          endIndent: 50,
          indent: 50,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the `BasketItemList` class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pharmacist_app/Models/basket_item_model.dart';
import 'package:pharmacist_app/widgets/basket_item.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class BasketItemsList extends StatefulWidget {
  BasketItemsList({super.key});

  get items => null;

  @override
  State<BasketItemsList> createState() => _BasketItemsListState();
}
 List<BasketItemModel> items = const [
    BasketItemModel(
      name: 'Paracetamol',
      price: 2000,
      image: 'assets/images/download (1).jpeg',
      amount: 0,
      counter: 1,
    ),
    BasketItemModel(
      name: 'Paracetamol', price: 10500,
      image: 'assets/images/download (1).jpeg',
      //the Amount of every drug. it will come from API.
      amount: 0,
      counter: 1,
    ),
  ];
class _BasketItemsListState extends State<BasketItemsList> {
 

  double sum = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverList(
      delegate:
          SliverChildBuilderDelegate(childCount: items.length, (context, i) {
        return BasketItem(item: items[i],index:i);
      }),
    );
    // ListView.builder(
    //   shrinkWrap: true,
    //   physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    //   itemCount: items.length,
    //   itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    //     return Expanded(
    //       child: BasketItem(item: items[i]),
    //     );
    //   },
    // );
  }

  double sums() {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      sum += items[i].price;
    }

    return sum;
  }
}
```

I want to delete the item from the list and UI permanently when I press the delete icon.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this method in the click of the delete icon

```
  void _deleteItem(int index) {
setState(() {
  // Remove the item from the list
  itemList.removeAt(index);
});
```

}

and while calling the method pass the index as the parameter.
i.e  `_deleteItem(index);`

hope it works!!!!